# How to find the minimum value in a jsonb data using postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have this jsonb data format-

> data

```
{"20161110" : {"6" : ["12", "11", "171.00"],"12" : ["13", "11", "170.00"],"18" : ["16", "11", "174.00"]}}
```

I want to find the minimum value out of the prices,
In this case-170.00 .
I have tried indexing but able to find data for specific terms(6,12,18) but not the minimum out of them.

> What I have tried-

```
data::json->(select key from json_each_text(data::json) limit 1))::json#>>'{6,2}'
```

which gives me result for 6th term that is 171.00

Comment: Don't you need to issue the same command (your trial) for each of the three elements (i.e. 6, 12 and 18), compare the results and pick the minimal value? You command is examining only the first (6) and returning the value (171.00).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the minimum value of the third element in the arrays, then you will have to unpack the JSON document to get to the array to compare values. That goes somewhat like this (and assuming you indeed have a `jsonb` column and a primary key called `id`):

```
SELECT id, min((arr ->> 2)::numeric) AS min_price
FROM ( SELECT id, jdoc
       FROM my_table, jsonb_each(data) d (key, jdoc) ) sub,
     jsonb_each(jdoc) doc (key, arr)
GROUP BY 1;
```

In PostgreSQL there are table functions, functions that return a set of rows, like `jsonb_each()`. You should use these functions in the FROM list. These table functions can implicitly refer to columns from tables defined earlier in the list, like `FROM my_table, jsonb_each(my_table.data)`, in which case a link between the two sources is made as if a join condition were specified between the two; in practice, the function gets called once for each of the rows of the source table and the function output is added to the list of available columns.

The JSON functions work only on the level of the JSON document that is explicitly specified. That could be the entire document (`my_table.data` in this case) or down to some path that you can specify. I am assuming here that the first key is a date value and that you therefore do not know the key in advance. The same goes for the sub-document. In these cases you use functions like `jsonb_each()`. The array position you apparently know exactly, so you can just index the array to find the price information. Note that these are apparently also in JSON format, so you should get the price as a `text` value with the `->>` operator and then cast that to `numeric` so you can feed it to the `min()` function.

Comment: Hi Patrick,Thanks for your quick answer, can you please explain it to me a lil bit as I am new to it.It is retrieving the minimum value from all the rows for that column, what changes do i need to do to find for a particular column.

Comment: See updated answer. I do not understand when you say "It is retrieving the minimum value from all the rows for that column". Can you explain that a bit better?

Comment: I meant it is taking the minimum from all the rows of the table for data column,if I want to retrieve just the min value from one row, how can I provide that row as a input in the query you suggested.PS:Thanks a lot! Loved your answer and nice explanation!

Comment: If you indeed use a primary key like `id` in the answer, then you should get the minimum for each individual row in the table. If you do not use a primary key, you can either use `WITH CARDINALITY` on the inner call to `jsonb_each()` and then change `id` to `cardinality` or specify the top-level key for a specific row, like `WHERE key = '20161110'::jsonb` in the inner `SELECT`.

Comment: Hi Patrick,Is there any way we can find the key of the minimum value as well in the same query?

Answer (score 0):

I created this funciton for this. Hope it helps

```
CREATE 
OR 
replace FUNCTION min_json (data json) 
returns numeric AS $$ 
BEGIN
RETURN 
  ( 
         SELECT Min(value) 
         FROM   ( 
                       SELECT (Hstore(Json_each_text(data))->'value')::numeric AS value) AS t);
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```